# Summing numbers with comma as decimal separator in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, sum, decimalformat

I have an XML file where the number are comma-separated

```
<foo>
  <bar val="1,23"/>
  <bar val="4,56"/>
  <bar val="7,89"/>
</foo>
```

I would like to make a sum over `/foo/bar/@val` values in XSLT, but I am a bit stuck the formatting. Does anyone knows what would be the proper syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing, that the value specified in a `"val"` attribute is a number that has comma instead of a decimal point.

**Several solutions are possible**:

**I. XSLT 1.0**

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 >
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
<!--                                           -->  
    <xsl:template match="foo">
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfBars">
        <xsl:for-each select="bar">
          <bar val="{translate(@val, ',', '.')}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
<!--                                           -->
      <xsl:value-of select=
       "sum(ext:node-set($vrtfBars)/*/@val)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the originally-provided XML document**:

```
<foo>
    <bar val="1,23"/>
    <bar val="4,56"/>
    <bar val="7,89"/>
</foo>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
13.68
```

**II. XSLT 2.0**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
<!--                                           -->
 <xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "sum(bar/@val/number(translate(., ',', '.')))" 
   />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document, produces the same correct result**:

13.68

**III. [FXSL 2.x](http://fxsl.sf.net)**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 xmlns:my="my:fun"
 exclude-result-prefixes="my f xs"
 >
   <xsl:import href="../f/func-transform-and-sum.xsl"/>
<!--                                           -->
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
<!--                                           -->
 <xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "sum(
        f:transform-and-sum(my:makeNum(), bar/@val )
        )" 
   />
 </xsl:template>
<!--                                           -->
 <xsl:function name="my:makeNum" as="xs:double">
   <xsl:param name="psNum" as="xs:string"/>
<!--                                           -->
   <xsl:sequence select="number(translate($psNum, ',', '.'))"/>
 </xsl:function>
<!--                                           -->
 <xsl:function name="my:makeNum" as="element()">
   <my:makeNum/>
 </xsl:function>
<!--                                           -->
 <xsl:template match="my:makeNum" as="xs:double" mode="f:FXSL">
   <xsl:param name="arg1" as="xs:string"/>
<!--                                           -->
   <xsl:sequence select="my:makeNum($arg1)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document produces the same correct result**:

13.68

**The last solution is more flexible** and can be used successfully when a more complex transformation of the values is needed before summing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very precise answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the same as Dimitre, that you mean that comma is used as a decimal separator, not as a separator for list of integers.

Pure XSLT 1.0 without EXSLT node-set extension:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:call-template name="sum">
    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="bar[1]"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum">
  <xsl:param name="node"/>
  <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$node">
      <xsl:call-template name="sum">
        <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/following-sibling::bar[1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + translate($node/@val, ',', '.')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I say this a lot, but it bears repeating:  the whole point of XML is that it provides data in an easily parsable form.  XML that contains data that can't be parsed as XML makes no sense; if at all possible, you should either fix your XML or use a different format.

Comment: But a lot of the world uses a , for a decimal separator. Why is . to be the only one allowed?

Comment: Robert, I completely agree with you. Yet, in my case XML files are produced by a 3rd party application that I have no control over.

Comment: The only decimal separator that the XSLT number() function supports is ".".