# How to add two timestamp value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<LogFormat> 
 <TestHeading>
    <TestName>abc</TestName>
    <TestDuration>00:08:80</TestDuration>
  <TestHeading>
  <TestHeading>
    <TestName>pqr</TestName>
    <TestDuration>00:00:10</TestDuration>
  <TestHeading>
<LogFormat>
```

---

I want to add all the TestDuration tag(i.e 00:00:10 and 00:08:80) of an xml file.
and I checked '[Summing numbers with comma as decimal separator in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/647991/500559)' but it didn't work.
Please help someone..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is this XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? 2.0 has extensive facilities for date/time arithmetic, while 1.0 has none - though you could check the extensions available at www.exslt.org.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="LogFormat">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TestHeading[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TestHeading">
        <xsl:param name="pSum" select="0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vNext"
         select="following-sibling::TestHeading[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vSum"
         select="$pSum + substring(TestDuration,1,2) * 3600
                       + substring(TestDuration,4,2) * 60
                       + substring(TestDuration,7)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="vNext">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSum" select="$vSum"/>        
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:if test="not(vNext)">
            <xsl:value-of
             select="concat(format-number(floor($vSum div 3600),'00'),
                            ':',
                            format-number(floor($vSum mod 3600 div 60),'00'),
                            ':',
                            format-number($vSum mod 60,'00'))"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
00:09:20
```

Comment: @Flack: Do note that even with XSLT/XPath 2.0 you have to do some not implicit casting from this `xs:time` to some `xs:duration`.