# XmlSerializer to deserialize decimal with comma(,) decimal symbol

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, decimal

I'd like to know if there is any simple way to deserialize decimal with comma decimal separator using XmlSerialier?
I'am getting exported data in xml format from other software and all numbers(price, quantity, discount and many many more) in xml file has comma as decimal separator.

Here is simplified example what I have tried to do:

Lets say there is Product class with Name and Price:

```
[Serializable]
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and I have xml...

```
string xmlExample = "<Product><Name>Coca Cola, 2L</Name><Price>3,50</Price></Product>";
```

when I'am trying to deserialize that xml...

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product));
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlExample);
Product product = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as Product; //<-- Error here
```

I'am getting error *There is an error in XML document (1, 57).*

Everythig works fine, when Price in xml is 3.50.

I know i could change Price propertie to sting and TryParse decimal, but maybe there is better solution (for example switch culture)?

Any suggestions, solutions and comments are appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Forgot to mention that my current culture settings already using comma as decimal symbol.

Comment: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116354/xmlserializer-to-deserialize-decimal-with-comma-decimal-symbol?lq=1) !

Comment: @EricDraven your link is to this question :)

Comment: Did you found the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt there is a built-in way because XML documents with numbers that don't use period are not XML documents :) OTOH, this answer has quite a few possible solutions:

[Summing numbers with comma as decimal separator in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647991/summing-numbers-with-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-xslt)

Comment: Yes I know that xml standarts saying that dot is decimal symbol, but the fact is that I'am getting non standarts based xml file. So I'am looking for workaround...thanks for the link I'll check it.