# Uninstalling pocket PC program programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, c, pocketpc

I want to write a program (create an exe file) to uninstall a program in WM 5.0.  I was searching in Google but nothing really show a step by step how to do this.  I had a step by step instruction on how to install a cab file programmatically, but I can't find something similar to unistall the program.  I have seen some suggestions to use DMProcessConfigXML but I never used XML before and  it will be nice if anyone could show me how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2008/12/08/uninstalling-applications-programmatically-in-windows-mobile.aspx) article. If I understood correctly what you need is to pass configuration xml to [ProcessConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.configuration.configurationmanager.processconfiguration.aspx) method.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply. I saw this article.  I did not manage to really start with it.  I was looking for the cfgmgrapi.h and i can't find it.  also i am not sure which language to use and how to start the project.  I got an idea of how to creat the xml file.  but i don't know how to create a project in visual studio to call this xml.  any help is greatly appreciated.  thank you

Comment: Hi, first you need to create WM project. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb250560) is how to do it. In your application you just need to call ProcessConfiguration method with your xml like shown in example in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.configuration.configurationmanager.processconfiguration.aspx)

Comment: this is what I have done: I will try to follow the steps in the link you pointed to as a starter. do you think the uninstall function is ok? Also, what ".h" files are required? main() { Uninstall(); } UnInstall() { XmlDocument configDoc = new XmlDocument(); configDoc.LoadXml( "<wap-provisioningdoc>" + "<characteristic type=\"UnInstall\">" + "<characteristic type=\"My App\">" + "<parm name=\"uninstall\" value=\"1\"/>" + "</characteristic>" + "</characteristic>" + "</wap-provisioningdoc>" ); ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration(configDoc, false); }

Comment: well in article mentioned that .h file you need if you want to call this function in native code (if you code your app in C). Your C# code looks ok. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: I am getting 
error CS0103: The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I used the Visual C#, Smart Devices, Windows CE 5.0, Device Application.  I inserted the code as follow:
static void Main()
        {
            UnInstall();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
then i inserted the code above right after the main().  I declaired it as Static Void Uninstall().
I am getting: error CS0103: The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context (in the last line).  How can I fix this?
also, i had to change the XmlDocument to System.Xml.XmlDocument.  Is this correct?

Comment: I added the System.Coniguration.dll file to the references tab, and i got System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, but there is nothing for the ProcessConfiguration.  what should i use? Thank you

Comment: You need to add reference to microsoft.windowsmobile.configuration.dll and in your code add statement using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Configuration. I think you using wrong class.

Comment: And for XmlDocument its ok, but you can add `using System.Xml;` and then you can use just XmlDocument

Comment: Nice to hear :) So now it would be good if you accept answer, so other users knew that this is the answer to problem.

Comment: Defenitly.  I did not expect it is this easy.  I guess without your help wont be that easy.  I was struggling for few weeks and finally decided to post it for an answer and i am glad i did.

Comment: Not really. I will try if you show me.  I have another question about the program.  how can i halt it so that if a program is trying to be installed while the unistall process is running to wait.  once the uninstall is done, then will allow the program to be installed. thank you

Comment: To accept answer you need to click on tick near answer(then it becomes green), also you can upvote if answer was useful by clicking up near answer

Comment: I don't see answer anywhere in the page.  I see "1 Answer" and then all our conversation under it.  beside it there are "Active, Oldest, Vote" tabs.  Above it is my origional question.  above my origional question there are "Questions, Tags, Users Badges, unanswered" tabs and above that there are "register, chat, meta, about, faq" tabs.

Comment: :D my post is answer and on the left under 0 and up down buttons is tick which you can press

Comment: For example look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116354/xmlserializer-to-deserialize-decimal-with-comma-decimal-symbol/6116419#6116419) can you see green tick on left? It means that answer is accepted. Also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is explanation