# summing nodes on the same level after a translate decimal comma

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

given following xml doc

```
<root>
  <row>
   <field1/>
   <tax1>10,00</tax1>  
   <tax3>100,00</tax3>  
   <tax2>150,00</tax2>  
   <tax4>50,0</tax4>  
   <field2/>
  </row>
</root>
```

I need to select all the tax fiels ( tax1 ,tax2, tax3, tax4 and translate "," -> "." and sum them.
can this be done in xpath 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimitre Novatchev provided a complete answer to this type of question here: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647991/summing-numbers-with-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-xslt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647991/summing-numbers-with-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-xslt).

**In short, there are many possible solutions:**

1. XSLT/XPath 1.0 + [`EXSLT`](http://www.exslt.org/)
2. [`FXSL 2.0`](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/) (in particular, the `transform-and-sum()` transformation)
3. XSLT/XPath 2.0

**Based on your comments, it looks like #1 and #2 would be of interest.**

Comment: the example works on 3 <bar> tags with the same name, i have 4 different names tax1 -> tax4

Comment: That's okay; there are XPaths that can grab only those elements. For instance, `/*/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'tax')]` will select all the elements you want.